# Can't make a script wait asynchronously for a certain time for the titles to parse before going for the next url

Tags: vba, asynchronous, web-scraping, settimeout, serverxmlhttp

I'm trying to create a script in `vba` using `ServerXMLHTTP60` to parse the title of the first post from some identical links. My main goal here is to make the script asynchronous along with setting a highest time up to which the script will try before going for the next url.

However, the macro that I've created always goes for the next url when there is a timeout without being able to scrape the titles from the links.

```
Sub FetchContentWithinSpecificTime()
    Dim oHttp As New ServerXMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim URL As Variant, Urllist As Variant, t As Date, sResp As Boolean

    Urllist = Array( _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=newest&page=1", _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=newest&page=2", _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=newest&page=3", _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=newest&page=4", _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=newest&page=5" _
    )

    For Each URL In Urllist
        Debug.Print "trying with: " & URL
        With oHttp
            .Open "GET", URL, True
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .setTimeouts 5000, 5000, 15000, 15000
            .send
            t = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
            sResp = False

            On Error Resume Next
            Do
                If .readyState = 4 Then sResp = True: Exit Do
                If Now > t Then sResp = False: Exit Do
                DoEvents
            Loop
            On Error GoTo 0

            If sResp Then
                HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                Debug.Print HTML.querySelector(".question-hyperlink").innerText
            Else:
                Debug.Print "failed with: " & URL
            End If
        End With
    Next URL
End Sub
```

***How can I make a script wait for a certain time for the titles to parse before going for the next url?***

Comment: Hmm, would you be ok sending all the requests up front then parsing as results are returned? IIRC, this is how async works, it doesn't wait for a response from the server before sending the next request. If you do, maybe something I did awhile back https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221316/108307 would help. You could add a max timeout in the while loop in the example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why those SO links take to long to respond but I tried with different urls and the following solution appears to be working in the right way. The credit for the rectified portion goes to the provider of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55289213/9189799).

```
Sub FetchContentWithinSpecificTime()
    Dim oHttp As New ServerXMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim URL As Variant, Urllist As Variant, t As Date
    Dim sPrice$, sResp As Boolean

    Urllist = Array( _
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NZDUSD=X?p=NZDUSD=X", _
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB", _
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL", _
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM?p=IBM", _
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UCO?p=UCO" _
    )

    For Each URL In Urllist
        Debug.Print "trying with: " & URL
        With oHttp
            .Open "GET", URL, True
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .send
            t = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
            sResp = False

            Do While .readyState < 4
                If .readyState = 4 Then Exit Do
                sResp = (Now > t) Or (Err.Number <> 0)
                If sResp Then Exit Do
                DoEvents
            Loop

            If Not sResp Then
                HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                sPrice = HTML.querySelector(".Mb\(-4px\)").innerText
                Debug.Print sPrice
            Else:
                Debug.Print "failed with: " & URL
            End If
        End With
    Next URL
End Sub
```